# Kendo UI datasource read() method doesn't execute

Tags: kendo-ui, refresh, datasource

Can anyone explain me why my call to the datasource read method works fine when I first enter my page, but fail to execute whenever I call it back to refresh the view ? For the record, I use Kendo UI web (not the MVC one) in a Microsoft MVC environment. I can clearly see in debug that the read never gets called, but if I try step in, I get into JQuery minified file... which is impossible to debug for me.

Here's a sample of our code :

```
var testDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Test/GetById",
                data: { id: options.data[0] },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    utils.hasPendingChanges = false;
                    myViewModel.set("isDirty", false);
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    utils.convertDates(result);
                    myViewModel.set("test", result);
                    kendo.bind($("#testForm"), myViewModel);
                }
            });
            cache: false
        },
        parameterMap: function() {
            return kendo.stringify(myViewModel.test);
        }
    },
    change: function() {
        var test= this.view()[0];
        if (test!= null) {
            myViewModel.set("test", test);
            $("#testForm").show();
            kendo.bind($("#testForm"), myViewModel);
        } else {
            $("#testForm").hide();
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function(data) {
            if (data.notvalid) {
                $(data.data).each(function() {
                    $("#errors").append('<li>' + this.toString() + '</li>');
                });
            } else {
                myViewModel.set("readonly", true);
            }

            return data.data;
        }
    }
});
```

The read method is called in a subscribe event like so :

```
$.subscribe("/Test/Detail", function (id) {
    testDataSource.read([id]);
};
```

And in the cancel of the viewmodel :

```
cancel: function () {
            $("#errors").html("");
            myViewModel.set("readonly", true);
            testDataSource.read([myViewModel.get("test.ID")]);
        },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the read operation as function you need to signify success with the success function of the event arguments being passed. Here is an example from the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read):

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: function(options) {
      // make JSONP request to http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products",
        dataType: "jsonp", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
        success: function(result) {
          // notify the data source that the request succeeded
          options.success(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
          // notify the data source that the request failed
          options.error(result);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: The original post passed parameters to the ajax call, can you provide an example of using a Read function that also passes parameters? I cannot find any examples like that in Kendo documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @AlanFisher You should probably post that as a separate question to get an answer.  However, as I came across the question I can provide a simple clue.  If you want to send data to your Read server URL, you can use the data: parameter on the ajax call.  For instance data: { Value1: 'foo', Value2: 'bar' }.